# Do we have to put the ajax code and web method in the same asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am having a question about JQuery Ajax, I researched some examples online, which put ajax code and static web method in the same asp.net page. What I am trying to do is to put ajax code in ascx control, and the static webmethod in a aspx page that contains the control. Is it feasible? From my test, I got problem that "the server responded with a status of 404".

static web method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<AppUtils.vAdviseComponent> GetPDFReport()
{
    //AppUtils.vAdvise.GetAllComponents(currentAssembelyID);
    List<AppUtils.vAdviseComponent> assebmblyCompList = null;
    assebmblyCompList = AppUtils.vAdvise.GetAllComponents(14);

    return assebmblyCompList;
}
```

JQuery ajax code in the control

```
    var tablecontent;

    $j(function onSuccess(data) {
        tablecontent = {
            content: [
                        {
                            fontsize: 8,
                            table: {
                                headerrows: 1,
                                widths: ['auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto'],

                                body: [
                                  [{ text: 'id', bold: true }, { text: 'component name', bold: true }, { text: 'cage code', bold: true },
                                    { text: 'nsn', bold: true }, { text: 'part number', bold: true}],
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                      ]
        };

        tablecontent.content[0].table.body.push("shit");
});


        $j("#pdfExtractBtn").button().on("click", function getPDFSummary() {
         $j.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "vAdviseConfigurations.aspx/getPDFReport",
            data: "{}",
            datatype: "json",
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: onSuccess,
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error");
            }
        });
    });
```

so my question is that do I have to put the ajax code and web method in the same asp.net page? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my test and the online examples, I think that we cannot do JQuery AJAX in two separate page classes.